# Is there a way to register hotkey on windows without conflict?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm writing a Windows program and I need to register a hotkey. However, I'm afraid of the conflicts caused by `RegisterHotKey()`.

Furthermore, Key Events are blocked when you triggered a Hotkey message. For example, you call `RegisterHotkey(0, 0, MOD_NOREPEAT | MOD_ALT, VK_UP)` To register hot key <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>. If you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> in explorer.exe, explorer.exe won't receive this message(Originally <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> is go up a level in explorer.exe).

Is there a way to register hot key without conflicts and blocking?

Comment: If you don't want "blocking" then you don't want a hotkey.  "Blocking" is what hotkeys are *for*.  If checking for WM_CHAR messages in your window procedure won't meet your needs, please explain what your actual requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN page for [`RegisterHotKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> `RegisterHotKey` fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have
>   already been registered by another hot key.

along with:

> Return value
>
> Type: `BOOL`
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call `GetLastError`.

In other words, `if(!RegisterHotKey(...)) ... deal with error ...` would catch various forms of "didn't work", including that the hotkey is already in use - you need to look at `GetLastError` to tell the difference between "key already in use" and others.

I think the whole point of registering a hotkey is that YOUR application ALWAYS gets that keypress, regardless of what is going on. Which of course is a bit annoying if it happens to be popular key in some other application, but it's still the point of registering a hotkey. If you don't like that effect, then don't register a hotkey, or use a more obscure combination that is less likely to be used by some other application. Not sure how else this can be solved - exactly what would you like the system to do if you run IE together with your application, and ALT-uparrow is pressed?

Comment: I hope the operating system lets both program recognize the keystroke. I'm curious how AutoHotKey did it(No conflicts).

Comment: I have no idea wht AutoHotKey is or does. But the description of the `RegisterHotKey` does describe quite clearly what it does and how it works - and that the relevant keypress is sent to the `HWND` passed to the function, or to the current process if the value is `NULL`.

Comment: I think you use a global hook to examine all key strokes and then decide if you want to act on them and swallow them, act on them and let them pass thru, or ignore them. This may be what AutoHotKey does.